# mpicxx linker doesn't link object with an executable : Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_main" error

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, mpi, linker-errors, mpich

I've created a test program Demo_00.cpp, which contains the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    printf("Hello world! \n");
}
```

I made the object file through

```
 mpicxx -c -o Demo_00.o Demo_00.cpp
```

But when I try to link the Demo_00.o to Demo_00.exe through the following command:

```
mpicxx -o Demo_00.exe Demo_00.o -v
```

I get the following error:

```
Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin22.1.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -lto_library /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/libLTO.dylib -dynamic -arch x86_64 -platform_version macos 13.0.0 13.0 -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -o Demo_00.exe -L/usr/local/Cellar/open-mpi/4.1.4_2/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libevent/lib -L/usr/local/lib Demo_00.o -lmpi -lc++ -lSystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Reinstalled MPICH through brew, used g++ compiler but they all return the same problem. Deleted all other MPICH installations on my device (including ~/sfw/MPICH), same problem.
Ran the command specifying the exact path of mpicxx `/usr/local/bin/mpicxx -o Demo_00.exe Demo_00.o` but ran into the same problem.

Comment: at first glance, that does not make sense... what does `nm Demo_00.o | grep main` returns?

Comment: On an unrelated note: Why do you want to name your executable program with an `.exe` suffix? On macOS that's not needed, it's a very Windows-specific thing.

Comment: If you build directly from source to executable (i.e. you skip the object file and the separate linking), do you have the same problem?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet This command returns: `warning: nm: no name list`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  I'm following a tutorial on how to use Repast HPC (an agent-based modelling library for C++). Same problem occurs when running `mpicxx -o Demo_00.exe Demo_00.cpp `

Comment: Since this is a C program, what if you rename it as Demo_00.c and rebuild it with mpicc?

Comment: For `nm` to work you jneed to add the `-g` flag.

Comment: `-g` is for the debug info. `nm` queries the symbol table, that is always generated unless you explicitly `strip` the object.